# Understanding quotient map

Tags: general-topology, definition

If I am understanding correctly, a ***quotient map*** can be defined in [this way](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_map) (actually I quoted the following from Munkres):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; let $p:X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective map. The map $p$ is said to be a ***quotient map*** provided a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Or in [this way](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Quotient_Mapping):

> Let $C$ be an equivalence relation in $X \times X$. The map $p:X \rightarrow X/C$ s.t. $p(x)=[x]$ ($x \in X, [x]$ is an equivalence class) is defined to be a ***quotient map***.

I understood the concept from the second one, since equivalence classes partition a set, which is very easy to visualize. (Can anyone answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244069/is-it-a-good-approach-to-heavily-depend-on-visualization-to-learn-math)?) My lecturer introduced equivalence relation and quotient space first also. Only when I need the strong continuity I will consider the first one, which is convenient. However when I read Munkres, I have no idea why those two describe the same thing (at least from my opinion). Can someone explain **why** to me?

Comment: I think there is an error in the link. The quotient topology is not the coarsest but the finest topology that makes $p$ continuous because the trivial topology $\{\varnothing, X\}$ is the coarsest one that makes $p$ continuous.

Comment: I am slow in getting the second definition. I think a quotient map must be continuous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you didn't provide a topology in the second case. Actually it is defined the same way as in the first case, that $U\in X/C$ is open iff $p^{-1}(U)$ is open.

And in the first case, a surjective map naturally induces an equivalence relation on $X$ with $x_1\sim x_2 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ with exactly $Y$ the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: So I consider union of all open sets $U_i$ (since each is open in $X/C$, it is open in $X$) which are equivalent to each other, and this will be open since arbitrary union of open set is open?

Comment: @MonkeyKing, what does it mean for open sets to be equivalent to each other?

Comment: Ah, bad expression. I attempt to mean I want to find $U_1$ and $U_2$, like $x_1 \sim y_1, x_2 \sim y_2 \dots$ happen. Any way, if this is wrong expression, how do I prove $U \in X/C$ is open iff $p^{-1}(U)$ is open?

Comment: @MonkeyKing, you don't need a proof. That is the *definition*. Otherwise where does the topology on $X/C$ come from in the second case?

Comment: Oh right, quotient topology. Thank you very much for the patience.